# Setting Multisite on Localhost XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost, multisite

I'm getting "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. " when trying to access the new site I have added on my Multisite.

This is a subdirectory install.
I put the code from the Network Setup to my wp-config.php and .htaccess files.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
Thanks for the help!

Here is some of the lines from my wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '3000M');

/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/avada/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

And my folder structure is:
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project-name

Comment: Please share your `wp-config.php` configurations and the directory structure of you **XAMPP** `htdocs` folder with you project directory.

Comment: I have updated my post with the code from wp-config.php file. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Long shot... Add **only** this line first `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);`, go to /wp-admin and enable Multisite, then add the rest of the lines. Works?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps for debugging your issue-

1. First make debug on by doing `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and then check again the error.
2. Then check the relative `.htaccess` file for the site. And make sure that it is updated after multi site installation. Otherwise it could create this kinda problem.
3. Lastly check `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');` again. May be it will be `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/project-name');`. I don't know, please check it and match it with the domain at `.htaccess` file.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. What fixed it was to make sure the `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev-deploy/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Line #2 above, on mine, originally said `RewriteBase /`. Just needed to change it to the main subfolder for the multisite.